# TypeScript: combine enums in a complex type

Tags: typescript, types, enums

I have two `enum`s and a `const` in TypeScript 3.7.5 and I'd like to use `enum`s to write a quite complex `type` for a constant

```js
enum Action {
  Jump,
  Run,
  Shoot,
}

enum Character {
  Foo,
  Bar,
}

type IDontKnow = ...;

const actions: IDontKnow = {
  [Character.Foo]: {
    [Action.Jump]: false,
    [Action.Run]: true,
    [Action.Shoot]: false,
  },
  [Character.Bar]: {
    [Action.Jump]: false,
    [Action.Run]: true,
    [Action.Shoot]: true,
  },
};
```

The problem is I normally use square brackets for types either when using `enum`s or when not knowing how many keys an object will have, but I can't use both I think ex.:

```js
const usingEnums: { [Character]: string; } = {
  [Character.Foo]: 'John'
};

const usingArray: { [name: string]: Action[] } = {
  'John': [Action.Run, Action.Shoot],
  'Jane': [Action.Jump, Action.Run, Action.Shoot]
};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess `type IDontKnow = {[key in Character]: { [key in Action]: boolean }};` [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsRQN4CgpQFKQAOANDlAEpgim4DKAFiigqQL5ZaiRQDC9AhgCd+iYIMxkAYkxpQAQkLYcEAT0LAoASQAiaBAGkQKAO5QAvJgDaAa2AqoSdHyEiEYgLoAuTFBt2H6PDIaF5QAEZMADbA-OisrADcHHBoAM4IUK6oIKneOnqGJuYSuJbOwqKCAHTSKKHYuKVB2VUEEIShAGb8kanAsk2ILZQgoQiCYP1kg8EgVQxMCF09fbKssmUCFW7VCoL1077NaK1Ey71TjUdDJyNjE5eNlsdzC8z3k2tsCUA)

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't realize to use the "in" operator

Comment: @AlekseyL. please post that as an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: @MingweiSamuel posted 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) with the keys as `Character` enum and inner object using `Action` enum as a keys:

```
type IDontKnow = {
    [key in Character]: {
        [key in Action]: boolean
    }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsRQN4Cgq6gKUgAcAaHPAJTBDLygGUALFFBMgXyy1EigGFGAQwBOgxMGGZyuAGItaeAEIiOXBAE8iwKAEkAImgQBpECgDuUALxS6AbQDWwdVCToBIsQgkBdAFw26PAcnF3R4ZDQ-KAAjFgAbYEEQaShOdgBuLjg0AGcEKE9UEBz-fUMTcysA3Ft3UXFhADo5FCjsQKDwosbCCCIogDNBOJzgBQ7bLrRGqhAohGEwMZS7KZBGphYEQeHR8dT92qF6ryblYTaVzsRu3v7-IZHljpq1mep5xeeXyZvpzdYnyW+3YHHSQA)